# Perl Chart::LinesPoints Unicode?

Tags: perl, unicode, charts, gd

I am using the Perl module Chart::LinesPoints for plotting a chart (Active Perl on Windows). The problem is I need a Unicode (utf8) support of the labels for the chart. However it seems imposible.

```
$chart->set(
        'title'         => 'Title in кирилица',
        'x_label'       => 'Hour',
        'y_label'       => 'Temperature (°C)',
        'title_font'    => 'D:\trebuc.ttf',
);
```

In the code upper let's assume that 'title' constains cyrillic characters; they are not displayed properly. And trying to point a ttf file for use causes an error. It seems that for 'title_font' instance of GD::Font should be used. However it is not installed on my Perl and I cannot find installation for that library.

Any ideas?

Comment: You do have `use utf8;` in your script using UTF-8 string literals, right?

Comment: I use it and my files are utf-8 encoded but it doesn't change anything. I know the problem is with the font, but cannot solve it.

Comment: Show us a complete, working sample script that demonstrates that problem. Also, does your font actually have the glyphs that you want?

Answer (score 0):

GD::Font is part of GD, which has to be on your system for Chart to work.
Creating new fonts for the GD extension is covered in the [module documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/GD-2.46/GD.pm#Font_Utilities), to which you should refer - but first, I'd try and leave the title_font directive out - does your string display correctly?

Comment: No. I forget to mention that I use the code posted as an example though it is incorrect (I mean title_font expects instance of GD::Font so this code produces an error). Without title_font there is no difference (the problem remains the same)